# Is there a way to use POST/GET Requests for messages, on your Personal Profile on Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, http, clone, messenger

I've looked through the API and it's all for Facebook **Pages** to set up a Chatbot.
I wanna be able to set up a Webhook/Listener for chats/messages on my personal profile (to mess around a little).

I'm asking cos I can see unofficial Messenger apps on the Play Store, and they don't look like just a web implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that using the official APIs.

Read access to user conversations has been removed a long while ago already, and there is no webhook functionality for this either.